# HTML head tag and body tag attributes

Tags: html

For what reasons would you need to use an opening body tag other than `<body>`?

Also, would there be any reason to use attributes in the html head tag?

**Edit:**

By other than `<body>` I meant a body tag with attributes like `<body id="mybody">`. I wasn't refering to something like `<someotherbody>`.

Comment: What other kind of opening `<body>` tag do you have in mind?

Comment: Please be more specific. Are you facing some HTML code that is making you ask those questions? If yes, can you show it?

Comment: @zneak - `<frameset>` would be an example...there are other cases besides `<body>` out there

Comment: @zneak something like `<body onLoad="">`

Comment: @Pekka I'm building a framework and I'm wondering if I need to take this topic into account for certain things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ONLY opening body tag is `body`. The `frameset` example would be for just that...making a frameset...not for replacing the BODY.

You can certainly use attributes on the HTML tag--in fact, you should. In HTML 5, for instance, you should have a `lang` attribute at a bare minimum.

Comment: All I am asking about is what are common attributes used inside the body tag and the head tag. But I did not realize framset was an option so thanks for that.

Comment: The W3C will give you the list of valid attributes. http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.1 As for common attributes, class, id and onload would likely be the most common.